# how can i get the info of ssd in asp.net code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this code

```
managementObjectSearcher ComponentInfo = new ManagementObjectSearcher ("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
```

What should i do to get the info of the ssd 
?

Comment: just to be clear... you're trying to list the drives on the *server*, yes? (sorry if that seems a weird question)

Comment: you have the code. that's great! does it fail? if so, are you receiving an error message? if so, what is it?

Comment: That should give you info on all the drives whether they're an SSD or not. What are you finding is happening?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of info are you looking for exactly? There's a lot of info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-diskdrive
and also here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk. You can run any query you want by running a foreach as such:

```
foreach (managementobject os in ComponentInfo.Get())
{
   //useful query information from os here...
}
```

I've actually just finished using this code to get the partitions of each drive and their relative free space to calculate the percent free space. I've also used it to get the model and serial number of the drives. You can do a lot here, just point and shoot.

Comment: thnx guys i will try it